# Some combinatorial proofs using Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

I have two questions to prove using PIE.

#9. Use PIE to prove the following identities:

(a) $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i{n\choose i}{m+n-i\choose k-i}={m\choose k}$

(b) $\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}{n \choose r}r^n=n!$

For a, I thought that I should choose k among m from RHS, but on LHS, I don't know how to consider $i$ elements chosen from n first.

For b, I really don't have any idea to understand LHS. Please help me.

Comment: What was the exact wording of the problem that was presented to you?  For example, with each of the two parts, are you specifically instructed that you have to use PIE?  Please edit your posting to include the exact wording of the problem(s).

Comment: Sorry. I will edit it right away.

Comment: okay, I'm done.

Comment: Hint for (a). Imagine $m$ blue balls and $n$ red ones in an urn. Select $k$ balls. Then the number of ways of getting all $k$ blue is the RHS, and the left hand side is [number of ways of getting any $k$ from $n+m$] minus ([number of ways of getting red ball number 1 in the selection] + [number of ways of getting red ball number 2 in the selection] ... ) plus  ([number of ways of getting red balls numbers 1 and 2 in the selection] + [number of ways of getting red balls numbers 1 and 3 in the selection] ... ) etc by PIE. Is this enough or do you want a full answer?

Comment: Can you give me a full answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

For (a), imagine $m$ blue balls and $n$ red ones in an urn. Select $k$ balls. Then the number of ways of getting all $k$ blue is $m\choose k$.
The left hand side is
$$\mbox{number of ways of getting any }k\mbox{ from } n+m =  {m+ n\choose k}$$
$$- \big(\mbox{number of ways with red ball 1 in the selection} + \mbox{number of ways with red ball 2 in the selection} + ...\big) = {m+ n-1\choose k} \times {n\choose 1}$$ $$+ \big(\mbox{number of ways with red balls 1 and 2 in the selection} + \mbox{number of ways with red balls 1 and 3 in the selection} + ...\big) = {m+ n-2\choose k} \times {n\choose 2}$$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

For (b), imagine having $n$ boxes to colour in $n$ distinct colours. The right hand side is the number of ways of colouring the boxes so each colour appears exactly once. It is easier to analyse the sum on the LHS from $r=n$ downwards. The number of ways of colouring each box in any colour is $n^n$. Then subtract all those colourings which don't use colour 1: $(n-1)^n$ of them; but you also need to subtract those that don't include colour 2, 3, ..., so subtract $(n-1)^n \times {n \choose 1}$. But then (PIE) you have double-subtracted, so need to add back, the colourings that exclude both colours 1 and 2, 2 and 3 etc: there are  $(n-2)^n \times {n \choose 2}$ of these. Continue in this way with the remaining terms of the PIE to get the LHS.